# Drag and drop from View to GEF Editor

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef, eclipse-gmf

I have a simple `View` with a `TreeViewer` representing POJOs.
I need to drag the `TreeItem`s from the view and drop them to a GEF editor (inside a multipage editor).

When I drag the item from the viewer to the editor area, the create request, handle drag and update request methods are called in the listener.
but when I drop the item `handleDrop`/`drop` is NOT called.

My `View` contains:

```
Transfer[] types = new Transfer[]{TextTransfer.getInstance()};
treeViewer.addDragSupport(DND.DROP_MOVE, types, new InstructionDragListener(treeViewer));
```

The `DragListener` looks like:

```
public class InstructionDragListener implements DragSourceListener {

    private Viewer viewer;

    public InstructionDragListener(Viewer viewer) {
        this.viewer = viewer;
    }

    @Override
    public void dragStart(DragSourceEvent event) {
        System.out.println("start");
        event.doit = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void dragSetData(DragSourceEvent event) {
        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) viewer.getSelection();
        Instruction ins=null;

        if (selection.getFirstElement() instanceof Instruction)
            ins = (Instruction) selection.getFirstElement();

        event.data= ins.getID();
        System.out.println("data");
    }

    @Override
    public void dragFinished(DragSourceEvent event) {
        System.out.println("end");
    }
}
```

The Editor is part of a `MultiPageEditor` and looks like:

```
public class MyGraphicalEditor extends GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette {

    public static String ID = "MyEditorID";

    public MyGraphicalEditor() {
        setEditDomain(new DefaultEditDomain(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void initializeGraphicalViewer() {
        super.initializeGraphicalViewer();
        getGraphicalViewer().setContents(ProjectManager.getInstance().getTestCaseTest());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureGraphicalViewer() {
        super.configureGraphicalViewer();
        getGraphicalViewer().setEditPartFactory(new TestCaseEditPartFactory());

        getGraphicalViewer().addDropTargetListener(new MyTransferTargetDropListener(getGraphicalViewer()));
    }
}
```

and the `DropListener` looks like:

```
public class MyTransferTargetDropLsitener extends AbstractTransferDropTargetListener {

    private MyTransferTagetDropFactory factory = new MyTransferTagetDropFactory();

    public MyTransferTargetDropLsitener(EditPartViewer viewer, Transfer xfer) {
        super(viewer, xfer);
    }


    @Override
    protected Request createTargetRequest() {
        System.out.println("CREATE REQUEST");
        CreateRequest request = new CreateRequest();
        request.setFactory(factory);
        return request;
    }
    protected void handleDragOver() {
        System.out.println("HANDLE DRAG");
        super.handleDragOver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateTargetRequest() {
        System.out.println("UPDATE REQUEST");
        System.out.println(getDropLocation().toString());
        ((CreateRequest)getTargetRequest()).setLocation(getDropLocation());
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleDrop() {
        System.out.println("DROP HANDLED");
        super.handleDrop();

    }

    @Override
    public void drop(DropTargetEvent event) {
        System.out.println("DROPPED");
        super.drop(event);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I edited your question so that it has better chance of getting answered. Please look at the edit and refer to [ask] and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in help for more explanation and hints on how to make your question even better. If something remains unclear, feel free to reply to this comment. Add `@Palec` in your comment to notify me, otherwise I won’t know that you replied. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The thing is, that there must be an `XYPolicy` installed in the specific `AbstractGraphicalEditPart`.